# My recyclerview doesn't show up when I change my activity

Tags: android

When my app start up the recyclerview loads up. But when I change my activity, like, when i go to ProfileActivity from DashboardActivity and Come back to DashboardActivity the recyclerview vanishes. I don't get the problem.

This part is in onCreate method

```
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.startListening();

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

This is the onStart method

```
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        Query query = firebaseFirestore.collection("requests")
                .orderBy("creationTime", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);


        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Request> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Request>()
                .setQuery(query, Request.class)
                .build();

        FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Request, RequestViewHolder> adapter =
                new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Request, RequestViewHolder>(options) {

                    @Override
                    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RequestViewHolder holder, int i, @NonNull Request request) {
                        holder.requestUserNameTV.setText(request.getUser().getFullName());
                        holder.requestCreationTimeTV.setText(request.getCreationTime());
                        holder.requestedBloodGroupTV.setText(request.getBloodGroup());
                        holder.requestLocationTV.setText(request.getLocation());
                        holder.requestMessageTV.setText(request.getMessage());
                    }

                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public RequestViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview, parent, false);
                        return new RequestViewHolder(v);
                    }
                };

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.startListening();
    }
```

This is the ViewHolder

```
    public class RequestViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView requestUserNameTV, requestCreationTimeTV, requestedBloodGroupTV;
        public TextView requestLocationTV, requestMessageTV;
        public LinearLayout ll;

        public RequestViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            ll = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ll);
            requestUserNameTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.requestUserNameTV);
            requestCreationTimeTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.requestCreationTimeTV);
            requestedBloodGroupTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.requestedBloodGroupTV);
            requestLocationTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.requestedLocationTV);
            requestMessageTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.requestMessageTV);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you are getting data in onStart method?, Can you try setting the layout manager in onStart(), why are ypu calling setAdapter both in onStart and onCreate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your code from OnStart to OnCreate. it should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Now I'm doing it this way. and it works.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

        setUpRecyclerView();

    }
```

```
    private void setUpRecyclerView() {
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        Query query = firebaseFirestore.collection("requests")
                .orderBy("creationTime", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Request> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Request>()
                .setQuery(query, Request.class)
                .build();

        FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Request, RequestViewHolder> adapter =
                new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Request, RequestViewHolder>(options) {

                    @Override
                    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RequestViewHolder holder, int i, @NonNull Request request) {
                        holder.requestUserNameTV.setText(request.getUser().getFullName());
                        holder.requestCreationTimeTV.setText(request.getCreationTime());
                        holder.requestedBloodGroupTV.setText(request.getBloodGroup());
                        holder.requestLocationTV.setText(request.getLocation());
                        holder.requestMessageTV.setText(request.getMessage());
                    }

                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public RequestViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview, parent, false);
                        RequestViewHolder requestViewHolder = new RequestViewHolder(v);
                        return requestViewHolder;
                    }
                };

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.startListening();
    }
```